# separate gulp Concat locations

Tags: laravel, gulp, concatenation, gulp-concat

I'm working on a project that has two separate js folders for user `(public/js)` and admin usage `(public/admin_stuff/js)`.

I'm going to have two `all.js` files , one for user section js files and another for admin section js files . how can i achieve that in a neat way?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using elixir, then:

```
// For admin
mix.scripts([
    'admin_js_source_folder/**/*.js',
], 'public/admin_stuff/js/all.js');

// Another
mix.scripts([
    'other_folder_js_files/**/*.js',
], 'public/other/js/all.js');
```

Other cases:

```
gulp.task('admin', function() {
    return gulp.src('admin_stuff/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/admin'));
})

gulp.task('other', function() {
    return gulp.src('other/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/other'));
})

gulp.task('default', ['admin', 'other']);
```

If your are using laravel 5, i recommend using elixir:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/elixir

Comment: thanks.Im using this way right now , but im thinking about using some conditional plugins to prevent duplicate code